# Deployment issue on Vercel Next JS 13

Tags: next.js, build, vercel, next.js13

I'm going to deploy my NextJS 13 project on Vercel, on the vercel website I get the error ReferenceError: window is not defined (attached the logs below). I don’t understand anything, the problem is that in my project I didn’t even use window or anything like that anywhere

```
[18:58:56.658] Cloning github.com/PurpleTooth/KilowattCoin (Branch: main, Commit: 36ef30e)
[18:58:56.899] Previous build cache not available
[18:58:57.770] Cloning completed: 1.112s
[18:58:58.018] Running "vercel build"
[18:58:58.475] Vercel CLI 32.2.1
[18:58:58.701] Running "install" command: `npm install`...
[18:59:00.976] npm WARN deprecated @types/react-icons@3.0.0: This is a stub types definition. react-icons provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
[18:59:05.352] 
[18:59:05.352] added 290 packages, and audited 291 packages in 6s
[18:59:05.352] 
[18:59:05.352] 107 packages are looking for funding
[18:59:05.352]   run `npm fund` for details
[18:59:05.353] 
[18:59:05.353] found 0 vulnerabilities
[18:59:05.370] Detected Next.js version: 13.4.19
[18:59:05.371] Running "npm run build"
[18:59:05.587] 
[18:59:05.587] > kilowattcoin@0.1.0 build
[18:59:05.587] > next build
[18:59:05.587] 
[18:59:06.058] Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
[18:59:06.058] This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
[18:59:06.058] You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
[18:59:06.058] https://nextjs.org/telemetry
[18:59:06.058] 
[18:59:06.139] - info Creating an optimized production build...
[18:59:15.096] - info Compiled successfully
[18:59:15.096] - info Linting and checking validity of types...
[18:59:18.069] - info Collecting page data...
[18:59:26.023] - info Generating static pages (0/5)
[18:59:26.127] - info Generating static pages (1/5)
[18:59:26.180] ReferenceError: window is not defined
[18:59:26.180]     at E (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/722.js:72:73)
[18:59:26.180]     at _ (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/722.js:72:539)
[18:59:26.180]     at B (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/722.js:72:742)
[18:59:26.180]     at A (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/722.js:72:1187)
[18:59:26.181]     at jg (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.edge.production.min.js:121:330)
[18:59:26.183]     at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.edge.production.min.js:124:91)
[18:59:26.184]     at jg (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.edge.production.min.js:118:9)
[18:59:26.184]     at jg (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.edge.production.min.js:123:11)
[18:59:26.184]     at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.edge.production.min.js:124:91)
[18:59:26.184]     at kg (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.edge.production.min.js:127:155)
[18:59:26.196] - info Generating static pages (2/5)
[18:59:26.199] - info Generating static pages (3/5)
[18:59:26.199] 
[18:59:26.200] Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
[18:59:26.200] ReferenceError: window is not defined
[18:59:26.200]     at E (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/722.js:72:73)
[18:59:26.200]     at _ (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/722.js:72:539)
[18:59:26.200]     at B (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/722.js:72:742)
[18:59:26.200]     at A (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/722.js:72:1187)
[18:59:26.200]     at jg (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.edge.production.min.js:121:330)
[18:59:26.200]     at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.edge.production.min.js:124:91)
[18:59:26.200]     at jg (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.edge.production.min.js:118:9)
[18:59:26.200]     at jg (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.edge.production.min.js:123:11)
[18:59:26.200]     at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.edge.production.min.js:124:91)
[18:59:26.200]     at kg (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.edge.production.min.js:127:155)
[18:59:26.303] - info Generating static pages (5/5)
[18:59:26.304] 
[18:59:26.305] > Export encountered errors on following paths:
[18:59:26.305]  /page: /
[18:59:26.347] Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

I tried to do the build several times, but still the same

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.